# hard time optimizing a query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm having a hard time getting better results on this query:

I have the following 2 tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `casino`.`mutualfriends`;
CREATE TABLE  `casino`.`mutualfriends` (
  `CustUID` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `CustUID2` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `FType` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CustUID`,`CustUID2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `casino`.`customers`;
CREATE TABLE  `casino`.`customers` (
  `CustFullName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `CustEmail` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `CustUID` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `CustMoney` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SmallPicURL` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT '',
  `LargePicURL` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`CustUID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The customers table has 1M rows, mutual friends has 500K rows.

I'm having a hard time optimizing this query; it seems like there is a table scanning using it. I would like to minimize the scan:

```
SELECT c.CustUID AS Cuid, c.CustFullName, c.CustMoney, c.SmallPicURL
FROM `customers` c
WHERE c.`CustUID` = '1:1542073175'
UNION
SELECT m.`CustUID2` AS Cuid, c.CustFullName, c.CustMoney, c.SmallPicURL
FROM `mutualfriends` m, `customers` c
WHERE m.`CustUID` = '1:1542073175'
AND c.`CustUID` = m.`CustUID2`
UNION
SELECT m.`CustUID` AS Cuid, c.CustFullName, c.CustMoney, c.SmallPicURL
FROM `mutualfriends` m, customers c
WHERE m.`CustUID2` = '1:1542073175'
AND c.CustUID = m.`CustUID`
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to get a list of all customers and their mutual friends? It's not quite clear from your code.

Comment: well, what i am doing is getting a list of customers which are mutual friends with a customer which his id is: '1:1542073175'. the query results are right, but its performance is poor, i am looking for a way to get the same results as the above query but with better performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need an index on MutualFriends.CustUID2 (a duplicates index, not a unique index; and not as part of the primary key).  The primary key probably gives you a usable index for the queries where the identified customer ('1:1542073175') is listed first.

Check the explanation of the query plan.

I think you're right that there is a sequential scan for the third part of the UNION, and possibly the second too.

Comment: I agree.  Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html, especially the part about multiple-column indexes.

Comment: but what would be my primary key? i need a relationship many to many, a customer can be a friend of many other customers

Comment: @mysqldude: Your primary key is fine - the combination of CustUID and CustUID2 is unique (though one might argue that if you have CustUID = 1 and CustUID2 = 2, you should not also have an entry CustUID = 2 and CustUID2 = 1, but the primary key does not enforce that).  You just need an extra index on CustUID2 that is not a primary key (though it is a foreign key to the Customers table).  It needs to be a non-unique (duplicates) index since the same person can be befriended by many people (as well as befriending many people).   The CustUID column should also be declared a foreign key too.

Comment: I have added an index on CustUID2 it solved the scanning issue, did not know how the mysql index system works that link was really helpful thanks to you all!

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT c.CustUID AS Cuid, c.CustFullName, c.CustMoney, c.SmallPicURL
FROM `customers` c INNER JOIN `mutualfriends` m
IN c.CustUID = m.`CustUID`
WHERE m.`CustUID2` = '1:1542073175'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it does not give the same results as my query, missing some rows, any ideas?

Comment: The query doesn't select properly.  If the customer doesn't have any mutual friends, then nothing is selected; if the customer is not a mutual friend with themself, then nothing is selected; it does not select rows where the customer is the primary friend of someone else; etc.

Comment: yeah i need that part where the customer is a friend of someone else. this query only covers one side of the problem, when i UNION the other side the table scan shows again :|

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this query:

```
select *
from customers
where CustUID in (
  select CustUID
  from mutual_friends
  where CustUID2 = '1:1542073175'
  union all
  select CustUID2
  from mutual_friends
  where CustUID = '1:1542073175'
  union all
  select '1:1542073175'
)
```

Is that any faster?

Comment: that scans all customers table for some reason :|